# cabal install djinn-lib with GHC 8.4?

Tags: ghc, cabal

I'm trying to install `djinn-lib` with GHC 8.4.1 (from Ubuntu 16.04 `apt-get`).

```
$ cabal install djinn-lib
```

But I get an error about ambiguity in the `<>` operator as shown at the bottom.

*Does anyone know how to go about fixing it?*

The cabal version I used was:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 2.2.0.0
compiled using version 2.2.0.0 of the Cabal library
```

The error message is:

```
$ cabal install djinn-lib
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring djinn-lib-0.0.1.2...
Preprocessing library for djinn-lib-0.0.1.2..
Building library for djinn-lib-0.0.1.2..
[1 of 4] Compiling Djinn.LJTFormula ( src/Djinn/LJTFormula.hs, dist/build/Djinn/LJTFormula.o )
[2 of 4] Compiling Djinn.LJT        ( src/Djinn/LJT.hs, dist/build/Djinn/LJT.o )
[3 of 4] Compiling Djinn.HTypes     ( src/Djinn/HTypes.hs, dist/build/Djinn/HTypes.o )

src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:242:29: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘<>’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.<>’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:5:8-19
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
                          or ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ.<>’,
                             imported from ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ’ at src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:36:67-70
    |
242 | ppPat _ (HPAt s p) = text s <> text "@" <> ppPat 10 p
    |                             ^^

src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:242:41: error:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘<>’
    It could refer to either ‘Prelude.<>’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:5:8-19
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
                          or ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ.<>’,
                             imported from ‘Text.PrettyPrint.HughesPJ’ at src/Djinn/HTypes.hs:36:67-70
    |
242 | ppPat _ (HPAt s p) = text s <> text "@" <> ppPat 10 p
    |                                         ^^
Failed to install djinn-lib-0.0.1.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
djinn-lib-0.0.1.2-72XYG7inpNR6A7gk4acAK4 failed during the building phase. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier `<>` was added to the prelude and it clashes with the existing one from HughesPJ. You can add the line `import Prelude hiding((<>>))` to the imports section of the files in question to fix this...